# Generic type in java for inner classes

Tags: java

I have abstract class with a generic type parameter, but it seems that the inner class can not access this type:

```
public abstract class DataProcessor<T> {

    protected interface CallBack {
        List<T> parse(String response) throws ServerException, JSONException;// error
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

---

update:

Usage:

```
public class XProcessor extend DataProcessor<X>{
}
public class YProcessor extend DataProcessor<Y>{
}

XProcessor xp=new XProcessor();
YProcessor yp=new YProcessor();

xp.setCallback(new DataProcessor.CallBack<X>(){
    ....
});
```

But I thought that since the `XProcessor` have defined the `X` in the class defined, so I wonder if I can ignore the generic parameter like this:

```
xp.setCallback(new XProcessor.CallBack(){ //without specify the generic type 
    .....
});
```

Comment: Let me know if the answer resolved your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for you are intending. To avoid compilation error add the type parameter to `Callback` interface.

```
public abstract class DataProcessor<T> {

    protected interface CallBack<T> {
        List<T> parse(String response) throws ServerException, JSONException;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Add the type parameter to Callback interface` that's what I tried to avoid. See my update.

Comment: @hguser That is type argument, not type parameter you've given. Type parameter goes with the interface definition.

Comment: well, your earlier question did not mention it. Will take a look and reply